# Сравнение элементов массива по индексам

Tags: javascript, массивы

Не уверен в правильности формулировки, есть два массива - ["1", "2", "3", "4"] и ["1", "2"]
Необходимо сравнить 1й элемент с первым, 2й со вторым и так далее, и вернуть массив элементов, для которых сравнение оказалось ложью.
Первый массив - статичный набор элементов, второй - динамический, в него добавляются элементы из первого массива, после каждого использования в функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то такое?

```js
let arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
let arr2 = ["1", "2"];

let result = arr1.filter((item, index) => item != arr2[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Абсолютно верно! Совсем забыл про аргумент index и пытался городить внутри filter циклы) Спасибо большое, Азиз!